# How to remove all directories owned by x users older than y hours?

Tags: bash, hive

We have multiple hive jobs that are running in our cluster. These jobs are creating "***_resources**" directories daily in the "/tmp/" folder of the edge node and not cleaning them up after it ends.

We are using **Cloudera CDP 7.1.7**.

Now, we have already faced a few **failures** where the hive job needed to create a resources folder but it couldn't because that folder already existed.

So, we need to **clean up these folders**. We cannot remove all folders because some of them might be being used by the currently running hive jobs.

So, essentially, we need to delete all "*_resources" folder that are in the tmp folder of the edge node regularly until Cloudera fixes the issue at their end.

How can we clean up only those folders that are older than 2 days owned by a particular user?

I would prefer a Python script as compared to a bash script. But any language is fine as long as it gets the job done.

Thank you.

P. S.: * Is a mask character that is used in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the find command

```bash
find / -mtime +30 -user username -exec rm -r {} \;
```

- `/` the path of the parent directory
- `30` the number of days to go back, for example, if you put -`mtime` +5, it will delete everything OLDER then 5 days. (if you want exact hours see the `mmin` below
- `username` the name of the user to delete the files for

> you can also use the `-group` instead of the `-user` if you grouped all those user in one group

I suggest you print the paths found by the command before doing the actual delete, just to make sure it is what you want

```
find / -mtime +30 -user username
```

If you are concerned about exact Y hours instead of days you can use the `-mmin` instead of the `-mtime`, it takes minutes instead of days, e.g:

```
find / -mmin +120 -user username -exec rm -r {} \;
```

the previous command will delete anything owned by user `username` that is older than `120 minutes` (2 hours)

Answer (score 0):

**man find**

> **-daystart**
> Measure  times  (for  -amin,  -atime, -cmin, -ctime, **-mmin**, and -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago.  This option
> only affects tests which appear later on the command line.

-mmin when the file was modified in minutes

```
hours=2
find /tmp -type d -mmin -$((60*$hours)) -user username -print0|xargs -I dir -0 rm -rf "dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to  dry-run/test `find` output command, before execution irreversible deletions.few times to gain confidence. Then automate scheduling with `cron`.

```
find / -mtime +30 -user username -type d -name "*_resources" -printf "rm -rf %p\n"
```

When you are ready and `find` located the correct directories, and constructed the correct `rm` commands.

Execute all constructed `rm` commands at once with:

```
bash <<< $(find / -mtime +30 -user username -type d -name "*_resources" -printf "rm -rf %p\n")
```